# exception without explicit reason when deploying U-SQL jobs to Azure by Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, u-sql

I am using python SDK to submit jobs to Azure using adlaJobClient , I have around 30 dynamic USQLs constructed using JINJA2, which I am populating in a list and then pushing them off to Azure using adlaJobClient one by one, The problem which I am facing is after a random number of successful deployments python throws an exception in the program console without any further explanation.there is no instance of U-SQL job failure in Azure either , below mentioned  is error stack trace in python , when I run the same U-SQL query,which I am generating dynamically.. for which the execution is stopping  it runs without fail in Azure (manually)

```
***** starting query number **** 24
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: Compiling
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: Compiling
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: Compiling
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: starting
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: starting
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 1
```

```
 for script in sql_query_list:
    jobId = str(uuid.uuid4())

    jobResult = adlaJobClient.job.create(adla,jobId,JobInformation(name='Submit ADLA Job '+jobId,type='USql',properties=USqlJobProperties(script=script)))

    try:

        while(jobResult.state != JobState.ended):
            print('Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: ' + jobResult.state.value)
            time.sleep(3)
            jobResult = adlaJobClient.job.get(adla, jobId)

        print(' ******* JOB ID  ********',jobId)
        print("****QUERY no FINISHED *****",sql_query_list.index(script))
        print ('**** JOB ID RESULT: ****** ' + jobResult.result.value)

    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError
        print ("xxxxxx JOB SUBMISSION TO ADLA FAILED xxxxxxx")
        print(e)
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete error message and point out the actual lines mentioned in the error?

Comment: ***** starting query number **** 24
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: Compiling
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: Compiling
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: Compiling
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: starting
Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: starting


An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1

Comment: This is definitely helpful. You should edit the original question to add this information there. You can format it so that it is easier for people to read. Not everyone reads comments, unfortunately.

Comment: done,apologies for the inconsistent formatting

Comment: good job! Just trying to help you get some answers.

Comment: @Abhinaba - It looks like there's a syntax error in your print statements.

        `print(' ******* JOB ID  ********',jobId)`

should be:

        `print(' ******* JOB ID  ********' + jobId)`

or:

        `print(' ******* JOB ID: {} ********'.format(jobId))`  To the larger question though, see example code in my answer below. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### Option A: Manually log into Portal

The easiest way to check on a failed job is to log into your Azure Portal (http://portal.azure.com), navigate to the Data Lake Analytics account, and click "View all jobs". From the list of jobs you can navigate to your job and view the output with specific error messages. (Keep reading for the automated method.)

### Option B: Automated Python Job

You can get the job properties with error messages using `job_result.properties.errors`. The below code sample will perform a "pretty print" of any U-SQL job error, raising an exception with those details.

Parsing the error info:

```
def get_pretty_error(error_message_obj):
    """
    Returns a string describing the USQL error.
    error_message_obj can be obtained via `job_result.error_message[0]`
    """
    err_info = error_message_obj.__dict__
    error_msgs = "=" * 80 + "\n"
    error_msgs += "=" * 6 + " ERROR: {}".format(err_info.pop("description", None)) + "\n"
    error_msgs += "=" * 80 + "\n"
    error_msgs += err_info.pop("details", None).replace("\\r\\n", "\n").replace("\\n", "\n").replace("\\t", "\t").rstrip() + "...\n"
    error_msgs += "=" * 80 + "\n"
    error_msgs += "Message:    {}\n".format(err_info.pop("message", None))
    error_msgs += "Severity:   {}\n".format(str(err_info.pop("severity", None)).upper())
    error_msgs += "Resolution: {}\n".format(err_info.pop("resolution", None))
    inner = err_info.pop("inner_error", None)
    for key in ["end_offset", "line_number", "start_offset", "source", "additional_properties"]:
        # ignore (don't print these)
        err_info.pop(key, None)
    err_info = {x: y for x, y in err_info.items() if y} # Remove empty keys
    error_msgs += "Addl. Info:\n\t{}\n".format(
        yaml.dump(err_info,
                  default_flow_style=True
                  ).replace("\\t", "\t").replace("\\n", "\n").replace("\n", "\n\t"))
    if inner:
        # If there's an inner error, concatenate that message as well recursively
        error_msgs += _get_pretty_error(inner, ordinal_text + " (B)")
    return error_msgs
```

Making use of this in a wait-for-job function:

```
def wait_for_usql_job(adlaJobClient, adla_account, job_id):
    """Wait for completion, on error raise an exception (with specific details)"""
    print("Waiting for job ID '{}'".format(job_id))
    job_result = adlaJobClient.job.get(adla_account, job_id)
    while(job_result.state != JobState.ended):
        print('Job is not yet done, waiting for 3 seconds. Current state: ' + job_result.state.value)
        time.sleep(3)
        job_result = adlaJobClient.job.get(adla_account, job_id)
    job_properties = job_result.properties.__dict__
    detail_msg = (
        "\tCompilation Time: {}\n".format(job_properties.pop("total_running_time", None)) +
        "\tQueued Time:      {}\n".format(job_properties.pop("total_compilation_time", None)) +
        "\tExecution Time:   {}\n".format(job_properties.pop("total_queued_time", None)))
    print('Job completed with result: {}\n{}'
          .format(job_result.result.value, detail_msg))
    if job_result.result.value == "Succeeded":
        return job_result.result.value
    elif job_result.result.value == "Failed":
        error_msgs = ""
        for error in job_result.error_message:
            # Loop through errors and concatenate error messages
            error_msgs += get_pretty_error(error)
        raise Exception("Job execution failed for job_id '{}':\n{}"
                        .format(job_id, error_msgs))
```

**Notes:**

- Because these classes are not well documented online, I used the `__dict__` property to explore all properties of the `JobProperties` and `ErrorInfo` objects, disposing of any the properties that are blank or which I don't need and printing the rest.
- You can optionally rewrite this code to call those properties explicitly, without using `__dict__`.
- Any error can have an *inner* error, which is why I wrote `get_pretty_error()` as it's own function - so that it can then call itself recursively.